# remove unused hours of the day in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to configure Fullcalendar to manage night events. So I have envents starting one day and finishing in the morning of the next day.
So currently I have this configuration:

```
{
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    defaultView: 'timelineTwoDays',
    views: {
        timelineTwoDays: {
            type: 'timeline',
            duration: { days:1, hours:7, minutes:00 }
        }
    },
    scrollTime: '17:00'
}
```

This is not the best solution because the hours before the specified scrollTime are hidden, but I would like to completely remove them. `minTime` is not an option because it also remove the hours after the midnight.

Comment: So you want to take a chunk out of the middle of each day?

Comment: If that's correct, there isn't a built-in way. I might be able to hack something together though.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should make this a [feature request](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen). But here's a hacky method.

#### Fudge the time slot labels

On [`viewRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/), grab the slot labels and add an offset to them:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    if (view.name.indexOf("timeline") > -1) { //if it's a timeline view
        $(element).find(".fc-chrono .fc-cell-text").each(
            function (i, cell) {
                var old = moment($(cell).text(), "ha"); //grab and parse old time label
                $(cell).text(old.add(OFFSET, 'h').format("ha")); //add an offset
            }
        );
    }
},
```

And set [`minTime`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/). Remember that there is an offset.

```
minTime: "15:00:00", //is actually 15h + offset
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/ez0nvbf2/1/)

---

#### Problems

Naturally this cause some issues.

- It only changes the labels. FC still thinks that the place labeled `5am` is midnight.
- Server sync issues. You either have to store offset dates or transform them from the server and to the server.
- The day labels might not be exactly what you want. They will show something like `10pm - 4am` as the same day.

---

#### Helper Functions

Something like this will be useful. Convert an event to an offset event and back again.

```
var offset = {
    _offset: 6, //in hours
    _apply: function(moments,op){ //sub/add offset from moment array, with null checks
        for(var i = 0; i < moments.length; i++){
            if(moment.isMoment(moments[i]))
                moments[i][op](this._offset,'h');
        }
    },
    get: function(){
        return this._offset;
    },
    //Add the offset to the event or moment
    //Real time/display time -> offset timeline time
    add: function(event){
        this._apply([event,event.start,event.end],'subtract');
        return event;
    },
    //Remove the offset to the event or moment
    //Offset timeline time -> real time/display time
    remove: function(event){
        this._apply([event,event.start,event.end],'add');
        return event;
    }
};
```

#### [Complete JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/ez0nvbf2/2/)

Comment: Thx @slicedtoad. I'll check your solution this night and I'll let you know... however +1...